# All *.sh files became CRLF in the cloudbuild drop output

Tags: git, shell, azure-devops, msbuild, eof

The `*.sh` files will become windows CRLF EOF in the cloudbuild drop output.

I have set the `.gitattributes` with:
`text=` and `* -text`  and  `*.sh eol=lf` on master branch.

And I have added all the files in my `scripts` folder with:
`git add --renormalize .\scripts` in my branch.
But the cloudbuild drop would still force the `*.sh` file into CRLF in the drop explorer.

`git config --global --get core.autocrlf` is input.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: For the cloud build, can you confirm if you are using Azure DevOps Service Pipeline？

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Yes. It's the ADO service pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

The cause of the issue is that when we cloning the repo to Windows Agent, it will auto convert the LF to CRLF. Then when publishing the Drop Build Artifacts, it will show the CRLF EOL.

To solve this issue, you can run the command: `git config --global  core.autocrlf false` before the git checkout step.

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: git config --global  core.autocrlf false

- checkout: self

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.sourcesdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Then the files in the Drop Build Artifacts will keep the LF EOL.

Comment: The problem is that it is managed by MSFT ADO and it's not a customed YAML that editable on  my side. The current workround I did is to add a ps1 script in my project directory that will execute at the final step to force convert all *.sh files to LF.